# Why am i getting the error "kernel/drivers/screen.c:7:22: error: invalid initializer char* string[] = message;"

Tags: c

I'm trying to make a print function for an operating system. But i'm getting this error. What am i doing wrong

```
void vgaprint(char message, char color, int len) {
    char* video_memory = 0xb8000;
    char* firstcharcolor = 0xb8001;
    char string[] = message;
    char stringindex = string[0];
    *video_memory = stringindex;
    *firstcharcolor = color;
    int nextchar = 2;
    for(int i = 1; i < len; ++i)
    {
        stringindex = string[i];
        char* charpos = video_memory+nextchar;
        char* charcolor = charpos+1;
        *charpos = stringindex;
        *charcolor = color;
        nextchar = nextchar+2;
    }
}
```

Comment: Try `char string[] = {message, 0};`.

Comment: You canno get the message from the title with the code in the question. Please use copy&paste to show exact message and exact code.

Comment: Your `message` is only one single character. Not a good start to initialize a string.

Comment: `char message` argument should be `char *message` or perhaps better `const char *message`.

Comment: @Gerhardh - Ah - you are correct.  I got this only after a slight modification to the code.  By bad. :)  (deleting comment.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is wrong, overly complicated and there are poorly chosen variable names (e.g. `stringindex` which is not an index at all).

- you want to display several chars and not only one char, therefore you don't need `char message` but `char *message`, or better `const char *message` in the function signature,
- you don't need to copy the message prior to displaying it,
- you don't need a special treatment of the first character to display, you can do everything in the loop
- yoo don't need all those intermediate variables which makes your code hard to understand (and it also might be slower).

You probably want something like this:

```
void vgaprint(const char *message, char color, int len) {
    static char *video_memory = 0xb8000;   // start of video memory    
    char *charpos = video_memory;          // charpos is current pointer to video memory

    for(int i = 0; i < len; ++i)
    {
        *charpos = message[i];             // set char
        *(charpos + 1) = color;            // set color
        charpos += 2;                      // goto next char
    }
}
```

or even simpler:

```
void vgaprint(const char *message, char color, int len) {
    char *charpos = 0xb8000;      // charpos points to start of video memory

    for(int i = 0; i < len; ++i)
    {
        *(charpos++) = message[i];  // set char
        *(charpos++) = color;       // set color
    }
}
```

Call it like for example this:

```
vgaprint("Hello world!", 0, 12);  // poor style because 12 is the hardcocded
                                  // length of the "Hello world!" string
```